# RtcMulticonnection joins no room

Tags: vue.js, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I made a very simple **RTCMulticonnection** app to try to create a small videoconference application. however it keeps sending the same requests:

```
https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?
userid=b1nxbxqjvhd&sessionid=mywebsite&msgEvent=RTCMultiConnection- 
Message&socketCustomEvent=RTCMultiConnection-Custom Message&autoCloseEntireSession=false&maxParticipantsAllowed=1000&extra=%7B%7D&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NaOzrYK
```

but no video feed appears, it seems like I join no room..

Here is the code :

```js
<template>
  <div class="main-container">
    
          <vue-webrtc ref="BaseWRTC"
                      width="100%"
                      roomId="Base"
                      socketURL="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/" />
         
       
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="joinBase">Join using vue-webrtc</button>
            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="joinrtc()">Join using rtcmulticonnection </button> 
  </div>
</template>

  <script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import WebRTC from 'vue-webrtc'
import * as rtcmulticonnection from 'rtcmulticonnection';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'
window.io = io
//

Vue.use(WebRTC);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },

  methods: {
    joinrtc() {
      alert("joining")
          var connection = new rtcmulticonnection();
          connection.socketURL = 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';
          connection.session = {
              audio: true,
              video: true
          };

          connection.openOrJoin('myroom19');
    },
   
      joinBase() {
        this.$refs.BaseWRTC.join();
      },

  },
  mounted() {},
};
</script>
```

Both with vue-webrtc and rtcmulticonnection gave me the same result.

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved it by downgrading socket.io to 2.2.0.